# Incorrect Div Height Returned at First

Tags: reactjs

I have a custom `NewDonationCard` parent component which contains `NewWidgetOverviewPage` and `NewPaymentWidgetFooter` components and is supposed to look like this:

[image: Parent Component Screenshot]

`NewDonationCard` is of `position: relative` whereas `NewWidgetOverviewPage` and `NewPaymentWidgetFooter` components are `position: absolute`.

I need to control the height of the parent element manually since the two children have absolute position, and therefore I am assigning the `style` prop to it that instructs the correct calculated height on page load.

```
render(
    <div ref={containerRef} className='relative flex flex-col' style={subviewStyle}>
        <NewWidgetOverviewPage ref={viewOneRef} className='absolute w-full' />
    </div>
    <NewPaymentWidgetFooter ref={footerRef} className='absolute w-full' />
)
```

The desired height is calculated by combining the heights of `<NewWidgetOverviewPage />` and `<NewPaymentWidgetFooter />` components:

```
useEffect(() => {
    setSubviewStyle(prevState => ({
        ...prevState,
        height: viewOneRef.current.clientHeight + footerRef.current.clientHeight
    }))
}, [viewOneRef, footerRef])
```

The problem is that when the page loads, the parent container target height value gets set to `536` which is too little - the correct height is `819`.

I can get around this in a "hacky" way by running a `setTimeOut()` function with about a 1 second delay which will trigger the resize function, but seems to me like bad practice and not addressing the core issue.

I outputted `viewOneRef` and `footerRef` values into console at the time of the `useEffect` code kicking in and found that `.current.clientHeight` value was set to `700px` and `119px` respectively which if added up should provide the anticipated height of `819px`.

Why does the parent height calculation return a wrong value on the first run despite the underlying `ref.current.clientHeight` values appearing to be correct at the time of calculation?

**Edit - Additional Debugging**
I have updated the contents of the `useEffect` function with the following:

```
const ref1 = viewOneRef
const ref2 = footerRef

console.log('ref1')
console.log(ref1)
console.log('ref2')
console.log(ref2)

const h1 = ref1.current.clientHeight
const h2 = ref2.current.clientHeight
const h3 = h1 + h2

console.log(`${h1} + ${h2} = ${h3}`)

setSubviewStyle(prevState => ({
    ...prevState,
    height: h3
})
```

And it is so bizzare to get the following output:

```
ref1
[Object ...where clientHeight is 700]
ref2
[Object ...where clientHeight is 119]
417 + 119 = 536
```

It honestly makes no sense whatsoever...

Comment: Try `useLayoutEffect()` https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#uselayouteffect

Comment: "it fires synchronously after all DOM mutations. Use this to read layout from the DOM and synchronously re-render." - React docs

Comment: I tried that actually, replacing `useLayout` with `useLayoutEffect` but to no avail unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<NewWidgetOverviewPage />` component comprises of (among other things) an `<img ... />` component which loads the image via the `src` prop. The reason that on load the parent sets a height that is too small is that the image hasn't yet loaded.

To fix this, I had to add an `onLoad` prop to the `NewWidgetOverviewPage` component which would call the resize function, and call `onLoad` prop function from within `NewWidgetOverviewPage` using

```
<img src={donationCardImage} onLoad={props.onLoad} />
```

Despite this fix, I'm not sure why the console output of `ref1.current.clientHeight` displayed the full image size despite then that same variable resulting in a lower-than-anticipated calculated size for the `NewDonationCard` parent component.

Comment: Thanks! This helped me solve my problem